# What math is needed for the inverse quantum problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

What sort of mathematical background/familiarity is necessary and/or useful in tackling the inverse quantum problem? As an applied math major with a physics minor, I'm looking at different senior project options. I would like something that is a marriage of math and physics with some practical applications.

Comment: I don't know specifically, but this paper may be of use http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9910253

Comment: The theory of Integral Equations and Integro-Differential Equations perhaps.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "the inverse quantum problem?"